# Another word for key-points of a certain entity

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, terminology

I'm looking for another word for key-points of another object/entity.

Example:

The most important things of football are:

- Teamwork
- Speed
- Condition

What do you call the three things I just summed up? Sorry for being vague, English is not my first language and truth be told, I'm going to have to translate the answer into Dutch, but I can't yet, because I don't have something to translate.

Comment: You left out "TV coverage".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could describe those three traits as *imperative, vital, pivotal or essential* to football.

Answer (score 0):

Try **cardinal** from the Latin *cardinalis* meaning principal, chief, essential.